# CakePHP login to app = login to DB

Tags: database, cakephp, authentication

we have a database with distinct login for every employee. Full of triggers checking permissions, writing logs of user activity, etc. Now I am writing a simple CakePHP interface to a part of it.

What I need to achieve is to connect to the database through CakePHP. Something like connect() method that will try to connect to DB with entered credentials and, if successfull, will keep that connection and access the CakePHP application.

Well, I am googling since yesterday but can't find any direction. Do you know about any article/example..., that would help me with this task?

Thank you very much for your time.

-Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is information on how to do this in the book http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

Comment: Well, I have found some idea, at last. Somebody wrote to create constructor in the class DATABASE_CONFIG and set the dynamic credentials there. But the question remains: from where to get these credentials? Can't get them from SESSION as that hasn't started yet...

Comment: right, you are trying to create something like php my admin? you need to create the database connection on the fly. https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/app_model.php#L366 you will also need to create your model instances on the fly https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/core/libs/models/behaviors/infinitas.php#L114

Comment: check if the words i changed are better for you

Comment: Man, you are right! I am trying to create exactly that. The phpmyadmin analogy didn't cross my mind, now is the problem much clearer. Thank you for the links, but... do I have to do all this? I don't understand that code at all :-) I'm too young for this coding skills. My boss will kill me. No I'm kidding. I'll kill me myself :-) The words you've changed are better, thank you. Well... I'm going to study